# Isolate code didn't work as expected

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Expected "Hello world" from simple isolate code shown below & didn't work.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

var mainReceivePort = new ReceivePort();

main() async {
  await Isolate.spawn(hello, null);
  await for (var msg in mainReceivePort) {  
    print(msg);
    return;
  }
}

hello(_) async {
  var sendPort = mainReceivePort.sendPort;
  sendPort.send("Hello world");
}
```

When following changes were made to the code, it works as intended

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

var mainReceivePort = new ReceivePort();

main() async {
  await Isolate.spawn(hello, mainReceivePort.sendPort);
  await for (var msg in mainReceivePort) {  
    print(msg);
    return;
  }
}

hello(sendPort) async {
  sendPort.send("Hello world");
}
```

Looking for clues. any thoughts?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean exactly? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: Why do you expect the first example, where you pass `null` instead of `mainReceivePort.sendPort`, to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example sendPort is not connected to the main isolate, it exists only in the spawned isolate.

This code is executed in both isolates

```
var mainReceivePort = new ReceivePort();
```

and each isolate gets a different `mainReceivePort` instance which are not connected in any way.

In the 2nd example the `sendPort` connected to `mainReceivePort` of the main isolate is passed to the spawned isolate and messages passed to it will be received by the connected `mainReceivePort` of the main isolate.